# How to set the access of a menu page for all?

Tags: routes

```
function onthisdate_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['blog'] = array(
    'title' => 'blogs',
    'description' => 'Listing of blogs.',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

what access I need to set to let all the users see the page?, because I am looking that page as admin and I get an message "access denied"

Answer (score 1):

If you set `access callback` to TRUE, all users will have access to the menu router item. That means **ALL** users.

```
 $items['blog'] = array(
    'title' => 'blogs',
    'description' => 'Listing of blogs.',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );
```

However, setting `'access arguments' => array('access content'),` and omitting `'access callback' => TRUE,` is the best way - check your permissions settings. You should be getting an access denied error at example.com/node page as well.

If you don't set an `access callback`, it would be `user_access` and the `access argument` will be passed to that function.

Comment: i've set access callback to TRUE, but right now I am in mysite.com/blog - and still getting an error access denied

Comment: is it a drupal-generated access denied page or a regular Apache/Nginx/etc-generated one ?

Comment: drupal access denied message

Comment: Access denied

You are not authorized to access this page.

Comment: Check your `menu_router` table whether the description is what you expect -- my educated guess would be that another module also implements this path. Or you simply forgot to rebuild your menu.

Comment: why my access callback is set to 0 When i set it to true in the module?, i've cleared the cache, maybe is there something more that I'need to put to make work this?

Comment: @HellCoder This is the answer to "How do I make a menu item accessible to all the users?" The fact that page returns a 403 error message is another matter, for which another question has been asked.